# Rails generating a form for an array of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Total rails n008 here.

I am writing an app where I am selling "space" from 1 user to another.

So I have an array of spaces in my partial _spaces.html.erb, which works fine. Instead of just printing out the list item each time with a button that doesn't do anything, I want it to be able to 'capture' that data with the button click, so I can use it in my model.

I have tried with form_for (couldn't find the object) and form_tag, and a traditional HTML form (caused security issue), but I can't seem to solve the issue. Maybe I am going about it wrong?

```
<% Array(@spaces).each do |x| %>
  <% next if x.capacity == nil || x.capacity <= 0 %>
  <ul class = "all-list">
    <li><p>Address: <%= x.address %></p></li>
    <li><p>Capacity: <%= x.capacity %></p></li>
    <li><p>Garbage Day: <%= x.garbaje_day %></p></li>
    <button type="button" id="buy-spot">Buy the spot</button>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller for Spaces

```
class SpacesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @spaces = Space.all
    @user = current_user
    if request.xhr?
      @spaces.near([params[:latitude], params[:logitude]])
      render partial: 'spaces', layout: false
    else
      @spaces = Space.all
    end

  end

  def new
    @user = current_user
    @space = Space.new
  end

  def create
    @space = Space.new(space_params)
    #puts @space
    #debug(space_params)

    @space.user_id = params[:user_id]
    if @space.save
      redirect_to user_path(current_user) #need to go to the last space
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    # update capacity user
    @space = @user.spaces.find(params[:id])
    @space.capacity = params[:space][:capacity].to_i
    if @space.save
      # redirect_to user_path(current_user)
      redirect_to user_spaces_path
    end

  end
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `button_to`:

```
<% @spaces.each do |x| %>
  ...
  <%= button_to 'Buy the spot', buy_space_path(x) %>
<% end %>
```

Also in routes:

```
resources :spaces do
  post :buy, on: :member
end
```

And in controller:

```
def buy
  @space = Space.find(params[:id])
  # then goes some logic
  redirect_to user_spaces_path
end
```

Comment: Thanks, im going to work on implementing that. I have never heard of the button_to helper before.  I appreciate the help